# Site: addons.thunderbird.net/nl/thunderbird/languagetoos is not updated for rel60 quantum

Tags: 18.04, language-support

My Ubuntu 18.04 thunderbird had a language pack nl for rel52 only.
Two weeks ago it  has been switched out because the current release is R60.2.1 and does not accept anymore this old languagepack R52.*
No problem in thunderbird Ubuntu 16.04 and LinuxMint19.
They have the languagepack R60 (NL).
As you can see on this website all languagepack miss the r60 update.
Please warn the richt channel for this.

Comment: Small error in site-name: /languagetools.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to install [`thunderbird-locale-nl` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=thunderbird-locale-nl) from APT to have *Dutch; Flemish language pack for Thunderbird*:

```
sudo apt install thunderbird-locale-nl
```

As the result you will get version *60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2*.
**Note:** you may need to remove localization add-on from your user profile to make it working.